# EMF due to self-inductance?

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, inductance

I'm trying to calculate the induced $-V$ in a DC circuit when current starts to flow, and reaches it's maximum value.
The inductance of the conductor is 1000nH it carries large amounts of current (1000A), what formula is best to know the $-V$ due to self inductance?

Comment: If the current is changing with time, it's not a DC circuit.  The emf is proportional to the time rate of change of the current through.

Comment: Well it could be DC as long as the current flows in one direction

Comment: @AlanZ2223, I think your definition of "DC" is a bit old-fashioned (or maybe it's more common in some sub-fields I don't work in). For the areas of physics and electrical engineering I'm familiar with, we often want to distinguish the steady-state solution from the perturbations, or to decompose a problem spectrally, and then it's more useful to call the non-varying or steady state components of the signal "DC", and all the time-varying components "AC" (whether the current ever instantaneousl changes sign or not).

Comment: @AlfredCentauri , in the beginning when current starts to flow isn't there back-emf due to self-inductance?

Comment: @Key, if there is self-inductance and the current through is changing with time, there is an emf and the emf is proportional to the rate of change of current.

Answer (score 2):

DC signals do not induce electro-motive forces, for you would need a change in the magnetic flux through your circuit which can only be achieved with a time-varying current (resulting in a time-varying magnetic field).
This, of course, assuming that your circuit is stationary, so basically you are not moving the wire around for this would change the area pierced the magnetic field, introducing a change in magnetic flux and thus an induced emf.

However, at $t=0$ the circuit is open, so there is no current flowing. 
It takes a finite amount of time (i.e. it is not instantaneous) for the current to reach a constant value: in that time, the current needs to rise from $0$ to $I_0$. So you have a time-varying current, and this causes a time-varying magnetic field $\rightarrow$ induced voltage in the circuit.

In general you would need to calculate the induced voltage from Faraday's law (the third Maxwell equation), which reads $\epsilon_{induced} = - \frac{d\phi}{dt}$ where $\phi$ is the magnetic flux and depends, among other things, on the geometry of your circuit. This knowledge is actually incorporated in the quantity called $inductance, L$.

Long story short, the formula to use is $$ \epsilon_{induced} = - L \frac{dI}{dt} $$ but you need an expression for how the current changes in time.
The minus sign just means that the voltage will cause a current that's flowing in the directin *opposing the change of the"normal" current*, so basically in the opposite direction (the induced voltage will be opposite to the the battery's potential difference).

You can estimate (roughly) $ \frac{dI}{dt} $ as $ \frac{\Delta I}{\Delta t} $ where $\Delta I$ is the change in the current ($1000 A - 0A)$ and $\Delta t$ the time over which the change takes place, say $1 ms$.